# Howto generate custom error message While using not null message in @RequestParam in springboot java?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to customize the error message, I tried defining message @NotNull( message = "Con parameter is mandatory") String con, but It returns only the default error message. How do I define the custom error message.

**code:**

```
@GetMapping("/search")
        public PageableResponse search(@RequestParam(name = "con", required = true) @NotNull( message = "Con parameter is mandatory") String con,
               Pageable pageable) {
            return rService.fetchR(con, pageable);
        }
```

**Error:**

```
{
        "message": "Required request parameter 'con' for method parameter type String is not present",
        "status": 500,
        "timestamp": "2024-02-29T12:26:15.541491617"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you don't pass con parameter at all, then `MissingServletRequestParameterException` occurs. If Jakarta validation fails, then `jakarta.validation.ConstraintViolationException` occurs. These exceptions you should handle to change response body. You can make it in `@RestControllerAdvice` class or directly in `@RestController`:

```
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintViolationException;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Validated
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/search")
    public String search(@RequestParam(name = "con")
                         @NotEmpty(message = "Con parameter must not be empty")
                         String con)
    {
        return "Success! Con: " + con;
    }

    // http://localhost:8089/search - RequestParam con is absent (con is null)
    @ExceptionHandler(MissingServletRequestParameterException.class)
    public ApiError handleMissingServletRequestParameterException(MissingServletRequestParameterException e) {
        String errorMessage = e.getMessage();
        return new ApiError(errorMessage, 400, LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    // http://localhost:8089/search?con= - RequestParam con is empty
    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public ApiError handleConstraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException e) {
        ConstraintViolation<?> violation = e.getConstraintViolations().iterator().next();

        //String fieldName = violation.getPropertyPath().toString().split("\\.")[1]; // if you want to get field name

        String errorMessage = violation.getMessage();

        return new ApiError(errorMessage, 400, LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    record ApiError(String message, int status, LocalDateTime timestamp) {
    }
}
```

Also using `@NotNull` doesn't make sense because if `con` is null a `MissingServletRequestParameterException` occurs. I took `@NotEmpty` for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @selvi, if this answer was valuable and acceptable for you, pls accept it as answer

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, but one of the simplest is just checking if your String is null, if it is so, return a bad request:

```java
@GetMapping("/search")
public ResponseEntity<?> search(@RequestParam(name = "con", required = false) String con, Pageable pageable) {
    if (con == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                             .body("Con parameter is mandatory");
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(rService.fetchR(con, pageable));
}
```